# How long does travel toothpaste last?

Tags: air-travel, hygiene, vacations

Let's say I'm going on a week-long trip and I'm  hoping to bring only one small travel-sized tube of toothpaste (25 g) with me. Usually I just bring a normal-sized toothpaste but since the trip is only a week, it really wouldn't make sense to bring one. This might just be me but I can tend to get neurotic when I pack so I really want to make sure that 25 g of toothpaste will last for the whole week.

In terms of my brushing habits, I tend to use the doctor-recommended pea-sized amount of toothpaste and brush twice a day. I was curious to see if there had been any studies or articles written about this topic and this is what I found.

Comment: If you use all your toothpaste, can't you buy some more?

Answer (score 4):

From my research, I was able to deduce that if used a pea-sized amount (0.01 ounces or 1/16 of a teaspoon) twice a day, travel-sized toothpaste would not only last me the week but it would go even further and last 28 days!

Who knew a tiny little thing could last almost a month??

Let me know if any of you guys have had any personal experiences with this. I would be so interested to delve deeper in to this "totally irrelevant yet relevant lifehack" that I have found myself devoting way too much time in.

From: http://maphappy.org/2015/03/how-long-travel-sized-toothpaste-will-last-you/

Comment: *twice a day*, perhaps?

Comment: You *researched* this ? Dedicated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's much more than a week if you used pea-sized amount of toothpaste twice a day so, I don't think so it's gonna be finished in 2 weeks. In my opinion if you buy 5g weight of toothpaste for your trip which is for a week and you brushed twice a day, it is good for you......

Otherwise, good luck for your trip

Answer (score 0):

A basic conversion shows that one U.S. ounce converts to 1.8 cubic inches, so you can get up to three brushings from each ounce of toothpaste. For a travel size toothpaste with 3.4 ounces in the tube, that means you can expect to get 9 to 10 brushings. Depending on how many times you brush each day, it's fairly simple to determine how long it will last you in terms of time.

Comment: I think your calculations are wrong. My 100ml (3.4floz) toothpaste lasts for more than a month. I brush twice per day using more than a peasize amount.

Comment: It is difficult to squeeze the last toothpaste out of a tube. Some will be wasted. So don't rely on the nominal quantity for your calculations.